# timing issues with keydown, keyup, focus, and blur in browsers

Tags: jquery, mobile, keydown, timing, keyup

The majority of my time is spent on the database side of things and I haven't been keeping up with HTML and javascript developments, especially when it involves any kind of "fancy" UI coding. In 2022, is there a **canonical solution** to the following dilemma for both desktop and mobile browsers, or is it a "moving target"?

When you want to present the user with a series of HTML `input` elements each of which accepts only a single character, as with an "enter your PIN" prompt, automatically setting focus to the next `input` when a single (valid) character has been entered, timing issues can cause havoc, especially when the user has fast fingers.

```
                       [ ]   [ ]    [ ]    [ ]     [ ]
```

For example, if focus is moved to the next element in the `keyup` event, a user with fast fingers can type more than one character into the current `input`. The following is excerpted from code that works OK (on desktop and android -- haven't tested with iPhone yet) but *only if the user types at a normal steady speed, not quickly:*

```
              $("input").keydown(function (e) {
                   var $el = $(this);

                   switch(e.key) {

                   //<snip> tests for arrow keys, backspace, delete, enter, etc </snip>
                   // in a `switch` block

                     default:
                        if ((/[A-Z]/i.test(e.key)) && e.key.length === 1) {
                            // allow overtype of existing value with new one
                            // without having to delete the value first
                            $el.val(e.key);

                            // to require a value to be deleted before it can be
                            // replaced with a new value, use this:
                            // if (! $el.val()) $el.val(e.key);
                   
                         } else {
                            $el.val('');
                         }
                        break;
                    }
               }

               $("input").keyup(function (event) {
                   var $el = $(this);

                   //<snip> tests for backspace, delete, enter key etc </snip>

                   setTimeout(() => $el.next('input').focus().click(), 0);
                   $el.blur();
               });
```

Comment: But why are you calling `.focus()`, `.click()` and `.blur()` on one element at the same time? Are they suppose to invoke some event handlers?

Comment: Blur is invoked on the *current* input element.  Focus and click are invoked on the *next* input element.  I'm having to figure out what these things do. Does setting focus on the second element have the side effect of blur on the previous element?

Comment: True. I didn't pay attention to the `.next('input')`.